# The best performing (theoretical complexity-wise) algorithm to solve this quadratic program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

> Find the best performing (complexity-wise) algorithm to solve the following quadratic program
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \frac 12\|\mathrm x - \mathrm v\|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & 1_n^T \mathrm x = \mathrm 1\\ & \mathrm x \geq 0_n\end{array}$$
>
> where $\mathrm v \in \mathbb R^n$ is given.

---

I have started learning Moreau Yoshida Regularization to try to solve this problem, as I was hinted by my supervisor that the best performing algorithm makes use of that theory.

I will be adding the work that I have done on this question soon.

Comment: Have you tried to differentiate the Lagrangian function $$L = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}  -\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}v_{i} +\lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}-1\right) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu_{i}x_{i}?$$ I suspect that your problem can be solved algebraically.

Comment: Are you looking for theoretical complexity or practical running time?

Comment: theoretical complexity

Comment: The Lagrangian approach yields the following dual: $\sup_y \{ -v^Ty + \min\{0,\min_i\{y_i\}\} \; | \; ||y||\leq 1 \}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem corresponds to orthogonally projecting the point $\textbf{v} \in \mathbb R^n$ onto the unit simplex.

- The problem can be solved analytically in $\mathcal O(n)$ using [Kiwiel's algorithm](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-006-0050-z) (e.g see [Algorithm 3](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01056171) of this paper). Needless to say this is the best possible theoretical bound.
- If you want something a bit simpler (implementation-wise) with essentially the same complexity, then [this](http://stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/DuchiShSiCh08.pdf) $\mathcal O(n\log n)$ algorithm  will do.

Comment: I would like to thank you for this paper. Algorithm 3 seems to be what I am looking for. O(n) complexity.

Comment: Glad to hear all of this was useful to you :)

Comment: Have 200 of my reputation =)